# How does $\int \frac{\cos^4x}{\sqrt {1-\sin x }} \, dx$ simplify to $-\int -\left( 2-u \right)^\frac{3}{2}u \, du$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int \frac{\cos^4x}{\sqrt {1-\sin x }} \, dx$$

Using a U-sub where... $u=1-\sin x$ and $du = -\cos x$ or $-du=\cos x$, How does the above simplify to the below?

$$-\int -\left( 2-u \right)^\frac{3}{2} u  \, du$$

I assume we strip a $\cos x$ leaving a $\cos^3 x$ but I am not sure where to go from there.

$$-\int \frac{\cos^3x}{\sqrt {u }} \, du$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos^3 x = \left(\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}\right)^3=\left(\sqrt{1-(1-u)^2}\right)^3=\left(\sqrt{u(2-u)}\right)^3=u\sqrt{u}(2-u)^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes!!! thank you.